# BEM and form inputs

Tags: html, css, bem

I'm trying out [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) in a new project (a form page) and am looking for the best way to mark up the form inputs.

I have a set of common styles for radio buttons, which I've judged to be an "element" of form field "blocks". So I gave it the class:

```
.projectField__radio
```

The radio buttons are not always direct children of `.projectField`, but they are always descendants of them. So:

**Question 1**:
Is that OK in the context of BEM?

**Question 2**:
For a particular field - call it the "colour" field - I don't have a standard radio button layout. They are part of a field with diagrams that is visually a block of its own on the page, so I've put it into a div:

```
 .projectColourSettings
```

How should I mark up the radio buttons? They need the styles from the basic radio buttons, but also need their own as part of the colour settings field.

Is it this?

```
<input class="projectField__radio projectColourSettings__radio" type="radio"  value=1 />
```

Or perhaps

```
<input class="projectField__radio projectField__radio--colourSettings" type="radio"  value=1 />
```

I'm liking BEM so far and it's forcing me to think hard about my markup, but I'm not sure which way to go on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the latter is the correct option:

`projectField` is a **block**.

**radio** is an element inside this *block*, so you identify it with `projectField__radio`.

And, finally, you need to modify this element:

```
projectField__radio--colourSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question 1 : yes, I think this is perfectly fine in BEM. The methodology adds a layer of abstraction and doesn't really care about your specific markup, so for instance whether your radio buttons (your "element") are direct children of the form field (your "block").

Comment: Thanks - yes that makes sense.